# Callback from 3rd party API Not getting current user in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, oauth, callback

I'm connecting to a 3rd party API, Intuit Quickbooks via OAuth, to get a user's credentials. I've implemented the callback as they require and can successfully get the credentials. Within the callback, I call a meteor methods function to update the profile of the currently logged in user with the credentials passed in as a parameter. However, Meteor cannot find the user.

I've tried using Meteor.Async and BindEnvironment, but I get the same issue. Is it possible to know which user initiated the request to the 3rd party API when the API returns to the callback?

```js
var stuff;

Router.route('/requestToken', { name: 'requestoken', where: 'server' })
.get(function (req,res) {
  var QuickBooks = require('node-quickbooks');
  var request = require('request');
  var qs = require('querystring');
  var consumerKey    = 'xxxxx',
  consumerSecret = 'xxxxx'

  var postBody = {
    url: QuickBooks.REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
    oauth: {
      callback:        'http://localhost:3000/callback/',
      consumer_key:    consumerKey,
      consumer_secret: consumerSecret
    }
  }
  console.log('abt to request')
  request.post(postBody, function (e, r, data) {
    var requestToken = qs.parse(data)
    stuff = requestToken.oauth_token_secret;
    console.log(requestToken)
    res.writeHead(301, {
      'Location': QuickBooks.APP_CENTER_URL + requestToken.oauth_token
    });
    res.end();
  })
})
.post(function () {
  // POST 
})
.put(function () {
  // PUT 
})



Router.route('/callback', { name:'callback' , where: 'server' })
.get(function () {
  var req = this.request;
  var res = this.response;

  var QuickBooks = require('node-quickbooks');
  var request = require('request');
  var qs = require('querystring');

  var consumerKey    = 'xxxxx',
  consumerSecret = 'xxxxx'

  var postBody = {
    url: QuickBooks.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    oauth: {
      consumer_key:    consumerKey,
      consumer_secret: consumerSecret,
      token:           req.query.oauth_token,
      token_secret:    stuff,
      verifier:        req.query.oauth_verifier,
      realmId:         req.query.realmId
    }
  }

  request.post(postBody, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (e, r, data) {
    var accessToken = qs.parse(data)
      qbo = new QuickBooks(consumerKey,
        consumerSecret,
        accessToken.oauth_token,
        accessToken.oauth_token_secret,
        postBody.oauth.realmId,
        true, // use the Sandbox
        true); // turn debugging on
      // test out account access
      qbo.findAccounts(function(_, accounts) {
        accounts.QueryResponse.Account.forEach(function(account) {
          console.log(account.Name)
        })
      });
      // save the access token somewhere on behalf of the logged in user
      var userCred = {
        token:accessToken.oauth_token,
        secret:accessToken.oauth_token_secret,
        real:postBody.oauth.realmId
      }
      console.log("about to call addQB details");
      console.log(userCred);
      //this method simply adds the userCred to the current logged in user's profile.
      //Whenever the method below is called from here, it never finds the user. However when called from the client it works well. 
      //Is it possibe to know logged user from a 3rd party API callback? / How can I go about this?
      Meteor.call("addUserQb",userCred); 
    }));

    res.end('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head></head><body><script>window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();</script></body></html>')

  })
  .post(function () {
    // POST 
  })
  .put(function () {
    // PUT 
  })
```

And the method is as below. (The method works well when called from the client with a fake credentials obj as parameter. But won't get user when called from callback in router above)

```js
addUserQb:function(obj){
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
      $set:{
        'profile.token': obj.token,
        'profile.secret': obj.secret,
        'profile.realmId' : obj.real
      }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what is going on here: The server itself does not have a userId. Methods that get called from a client are called via the DDP protocol, which is a persistent connection created by the client and associated with a userId, so those methods do get a userId in their context.

A http request from a path set up by Router is not associated with any DDP session and cannot have a userId. bindEnvironment() will not help you here, it only works with callback **functions** running in nodejs fibers that were associated with a method originally called over DDP.

You have a callback **http request** from a different server. This comes via a different route and does not have any association with the server method that sent the original request to the Oauth provider.

Solution: You need to add the userId information to the request to Quickbooks, maybe in the callback URL, so that when the Quickbooks Oauth server makes the callback, there is a userId that you can extract from the request.

Comment: This makes more sense now. Haven't tried your solution yet but will work on it. Thank you!